# Running a "System Events" automation using crontab in MacOS

Tags: macos, automation, crontab

update -
the crontab is running the binary, but nothing happens, no errors or any output. it's have the same behavior as if it has no permissions the change the system settings

I want to execute [dark-mode](https://github.com/sindresorhus/dark-mode) project using crontab on every system startup.
To make this app work I need to grant in "System Events" permission under "Automation" menu in "Privacy & Security" settings in the macos.

The problem it that when I run it from crontab, it's not working, and I believe it's because crontab is not allowed to automate "System Events"

Someone have any idea how to grant crontab these permissions?

Comment: What exactly is your crontab record for the app?

Comment: @reboot /bin/dark-mode

and it works, the app is running, but nothing happens

Comment: Please always edit the question if you add further details. "nothing happens", but are there any errors in the logs?